# How to read HTTP response from Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to push a file (put blob request) to the Azure CDN Blob storage using the python SDK. It works no problem, I just can't figure out how to read the header information in the response. According to the docs, its supposed to send back a 201 status if it is successful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/

```
from azure.storage import BlobService
blob_service = BlobService(account_name='accountnamehere', account_key='apikeyhere')
file_contents = open('path/to/image.jpg').read()
blob_service.put_blob(CONTAINER, 'filename.jpg', file_contents, x_ms_blob_type='BlockBlob', x_ms_blob_content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why do you want to read the response header information?

Answer (score -1):

You can't read the response code.

Source code for SDK is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blobservice.py#L603), and in the current version put_blob() function does not return anything.

Do you need to read it though? If put_blob completes succesfully, then your code continues from the next statement. If it were to fail, then the SDK will raise an exception which you can then catch.

You could verify your exception/error handling by using a wrong access key for example.